# Update value on keyup using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have here an example that demonstrates my current situation.

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/solomon099/547atsrz/6/)

My problem is that when I copied the row, and change the value, the other qty of the item has not change. Like when copied the item of monitor with the total qty of 100 and my first input is 50. Then the copied item qty should be change.

[image: Click me]

The picture shows what I am trying to achieve. The red tells that when I change the awarded qty, the qty should also change. But unfortunately, that didn't happen in my code.

This is some of my code.

```
$('.awarded_qty').on("keyup", function() {


          var id = this.id;
          var num = id.split('-');

          var awarded_qty = $(this).val();
          var unit_price = $('#unit_price-'+num[1]).val();
          var new_rows = $('#supplier-table tbody tr.newClass').length;
          var orig = $('#orig-'+num[1]).val();


          if (awarded_qty != '') { $('#copy-'+num[1]).prop('disabled',false); }else{ $('#copy-'+num[1]).prop('disabled',true); }


          var aoq_id = $(this).data('aoq_id');
          var value = $(this).val();
          var sum = 0;
          $("#supplier-table .awarded_qty").filter(function(){ 
            if ($(this).data("aoq_id") == aoq_id){
              sum += parseFloat(value);
            }
          });
          // console.log(sum);
          $('#for_rem-'+num[1]).val(sum);


          if (unit_price != '' && new_rows == 0) {
              var tots = parseFloat(awarded_qty) * parseFloat(unit_price);
              var comma_tots = numberWithCommas(tots);
              $('#total-'+num[1]).val( comma_tots );

          }

          if (unit_price != '' && new_rows != 0) {
            var tots = parseFloat(awarded_qty) * parseFloat(unit_price);
            var comma_tots = numberWithCommas(tots);
            $('#total-'+num[1]).val( comma_tots );
          }






          qty_control(num[1]);
          if (unit_price != '' && $('#awarded_supplier-'+num[1]).val() != '' ) {

            refresh_index();

          }

      });
```

**Note. The original item must not change as you type. Only the qty of the copied item.**

Comment: It's great that you have included code and a fiddle, but I think it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: @Cat what I am trying to do is just like in the picture. Assume that those three rows has the same item. Now when I change the first awarded qty the second and third row qty should change.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are looking for is something like this. I've removed other columns and scripts for the sake of the cleanliness of this example.

```js
function updateQuantities() {
  var sumOfAwarded = 0;
  $("#supplier-table tbody tr").each(function() {
   var row = $(this);
   var quantityInput = row.find(".qty");
    var quantity = parseInt(quantityInput.data("qty"));
    quantityInput.val(quantity - sumOfAwarded);
    
    var awardedQuantity = parseInt(row.find(".awarded_qty").val());
    awardedQuantity = isNaN(awardedQuantity) ? 0 : awardedQuantity;
    sumOfAwarded += awardedQuantity;
  });
}

$(function() {
  $(".qty").each(function(i, elm) {
   $(elm).attr("data-qty", elm.value);
  });
  
  $(".awarded_qty").keyup(updateQuantities);
  updateQuantities();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="supplier-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Qty</th>
      <th>Awarded Quantity</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty" value="2000" readonly="readonly" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="awarded_qty" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty" value="2000" readonly="readonly" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="awarded_qty" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty" value="2000" readonly="readonly" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="awarded_qty" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```